# How to check the particular data in range using mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I tried to search MongoDB id in a particular date range using MongoDB query. but it's throwing an error can anyone give any suggestion.

**Mongo DB Data**

```
[{
id:1,
full_name:"naveen",
date:"2019-11-02"
},{
id:2,
full_name:"naveen123",
date:"2019-11-04"
}]
```

**mongodb query**

```
db.collection.find({id:1,date:{ '$gte': 2019-11-02,
     '$lt': 2019-11-06 }})
```

Comment: Here is an example of querying for a range: [Query for ranges](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-for-ranges). Also, the `date` field is a string in the input document, but you are not using it as a string in the query filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing commas for date values in the query.

Modify your query like below:

```
db.collection.find({id:1, date:{ "$gte": "2019-11-02", "$lt": "2019-11-06" }});
```

This is how you may like to do it, but not me.

There are some changes I suggest you should do if you are not already doing it.

**1.** If you are storing dates as strings in DB, don't do that.

**use proper Date format**, both while querying and storing.

**2.**  use below format of query:

```
db.collection.find({id:1, date:{ /* cond1 */ }, 
     date: { /* cond2 */ }
});
```